# performing multiple functions on every columns and rows of a list of dataframes using their names stored in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

**DATA**

```
foo <- dplyr::tibble(a=c("a","b",NA),b=c("a","b","c"),colC=NA)
bar <- dplyr::tibble(a=c("a","b",NA),b=c("a","b","c"),colC=NA)
all_tibbles <- c("foo","bar")
lapply(mget(all_list), function(y) sapply(y, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
```

> ```
> $foo
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   a     b     colC 
>   <chr> <chr> <lgl>
> 1 a     a     NA   
> 2 b     b     NA   
> 3 NA    c     NA   
>
> $bar
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   a     b     colC 
>   <chr> <chr> <lgl>
> 1 a     a     NA   
> 2 b     b     NA   
> 3 NA    c     NA
> ```

I would like to remove all columns from every data frame in `mget(all_list)`
This created the logical vector using base apply functions.

```
lapply(mget(all_tibbles), function(y) sapply(y, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
```

Then remove all rows with the minimum number of missing values

```
lapply(mget(all_tibbles),function(x)
x[-which.min(rowSums((!is.na(x)))),])
```

and then store these back in the same variables foo and bar. I have a large character vector with tibble names btw.
Can I use a tidyr package to simplify things? base functions are fairly complicated, and am trying to avoid for loops

Comment: A doubt, for the removal of rows/columns, which one is done first and is it stored as a single edited output

Comment: Separate outputs for now! Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Ok, then my solutions should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) 
library(stringr)   
out <- mget(all_tibbles) %>% 
     map(~ .x %>%
               select_if(~ any(!is.na(.))))
out
#$foo
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  a     b    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a    
#2 b     b    
#3 <NA>  c    

#$bar
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  a     b    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a    
#2 b     b    
#3 <NA>  c    


names(out) <- str_c(names(out), "_edited")
```

If we need to update "foo", "bar" (not recommended)

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using `keep`

```
mget(all_tibbles) %>%
       map(~ keep(.x, colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0))
```

---

For the second case with rows

```
out1 <- mget(all_tibbles) %>% 
            map(~ .x %>% 
                     slice(-which.min(rowSums(!is.na(.)))))

names(out2) <- str_c(names(out), "_edited2")
list2env(out2, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or we can use `Filter` from `base R` to remove columns (OP already showed a base R option for removing rows)

```
lapply(mget(all_tibbles), function(x) 
       Filter(function(y) any(!is.na(y)), x))
```

Comment: How do I set the outout of this back into foo and bar? Bash equivalent would be `for i in all_tibbles;do i = function ...; done

Comment: sorry if am asking too much. how about setting those equal to foo_edited bar_edited? I wanna do something similar to `for (i in c("foo_edited","bar_edited")){  i <- mget(all_tibbles) %>% 
     map(~ .x %>%
               select_if(~ any(!is.na(.))))[[i]]}`

Comment: @user171558. Just set the names of the `out` with `names(out) <- c("foo_edited","bar_edited")` and then use `list2env`

Comment: for the slice part, is there a better solution aside from `which(rowSums(!is.na(.)) == min(rowSums(!is.na(.))))` Because I only could remove one row with `-which.min`

Comment: @user171558 In that case, you can use `filter` as in the other solution `mget(all_tibbles) %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(new = rowSums(!is.na(.))) %>% filter(new != min(new)) %>% select(-new) )`